# Como resolver esses erro no android studio 2.3?

Tags: android, android-studio

como resolvo esses novos erros ! o layout não funciona antes funcionava! eu tinha mudado o build versão 26.0.0 para 25.2 ajudou mas depois apareceu esses 4 erros

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Altere as versões de todas as bibliotecas de 26.0.0-alpha1 para a versão 25.

Comment: ajudou a resolver dois dos 4 erros obrigado!

Comment: Quais são os outros dois?

Comment: Você pode tentar um File -> Invalidate Cache